# Which PHP functions and keywords instantiate a class?

Tags: php, class, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I'd like to know which PHP functions and keywords initiate the <strike>instantiation</strike> loading of a class definition file.

I know of these two:

1. The `new` keyword
2. The `class_exists()` function (if called with `$autoload` argument set to `true`)

I'm sure there must be more, but I haven't been able to find any more.

Any additions to the list would be appreciated.

Comment: Only `new` instantiates a class... checking existence will not create an object of the class.

Comment: Not clear if you mean "load a class" or "create an object".

Comment: Either way, you forgot `unserialize()`.

Comment: `class_exists` does not instantiate a class, it will only check for the class definition. But in addition to `unserialize` there is the [`PDO::FETCH_CLASS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method of retrieving database results with PDO and there are functions with the option to provide a custom class name, such as [`mysqli_fetch_object`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) and the [SimpleXML functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php).

Comment: You can also instantiate a class using [`ReflectionClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php).

Comment: You all make good points. I have edited the question to be more precise. Also, thank you for your input!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your edit is a big change. When it comes to loading a class definition file, you’re talking about the `include`/`require` statements and autoloaders. `eval` can create a class definition and then there are anonymous classes.